# How can I delete a special blank-space in a line?

Tags: shell, sed

```
{{tag>[ virtualization kvm]}}
```

I want to delete the 1st blank-space after '[', and the line is the 1st line in a file.

Comment: Could you please post your efforts in your post which you have put in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If it is first line only and its 1st space which you want to remove then following may help you in same(tested in GNU `sed`)

```
sed 's/ //1'  Input_file
```

As per oguzismail's comment adding following solution too now.

```
sed 's/ //;q'  Input_file
```

Comment: Why not `s/ //;q`??

Comment: @oguzismail, sure thanks for letting me know, added it now too, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
> cat mcro.txt
{{tag>[ virtualization kvm]}}
abc def
blah blah..
hello
```

If you want only the first line with the changes

```
> perl -ne '  print if $.==1 and s/\[ /\[/ ' mcro.txt
{{tag>[virtualization kvm]}}
> perl -ne ' s/\[ /\[/ ; print ; exit ' mcro.txt
{{tag>[virtualization kvm]}}
>
```

If you want all the lines with the changes

```
> perl -ne ' s/\[ /\[/ if $.==1; print ' mcro.txt
{{tag>[virtualization kvm]}}
abc def
blah blah..
hello
>
```